# Joining two tables with an auxiliary table

Tags: sql, t-sql, inner-join

I have two tables, `Chat` and `Message`. And another table names `chat_message_join`. The schema looks like this:

```
+-----------+  +--------------+  +---------------------+
| chat      |  | message      |  |chat_message_join    |
+-----------+  +--------------+  |---------------------+
| chat_ID   |  |message_ID    |  |chat_ID              |
| contact   |  |message       |  |message_ID           |
+-----------+  -------------- +  +---------------------+
```

Now i want to have another table that containts `contact` from the `chat` table and `message` from the `message` table. The new table schema would look like this:

```
+-----------+
|message_new|
+-----------+
|contact    |
|message    |
+-----------+
```

What would the T-SQL query look like?

Comment: Is chat_id and messageid is a foreignkey?

Comment: what exactly your question? Can you please explain briefly?

Comment: @JimMacaulay chat_ID and message_ID of chat_message_join table is the chat_ID and MessageID of the chat and message table

Comment: @InnovaITveSolutions I want to populate the message_new table with contact and message using the other three tables with a tsql query

Answer (score 0):

This query should get you there.

```
select chat.contact, message.message from chat 
inner join chat_message_join on chat.chat_ID = chat_message_join.chat_ID
inner join message on chat_message_join.message_ID = message.message_ID
```

to insert to a new table, use

```
insert into whatever_table (contact,message)
select chat.contact, message.message from chat 
inner join chat_message_join on chat.chat_ID = chat_message_join.chat_ID
inner join message on chat_message_join.message_ID = message.message_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question, Something like

```
SELECT a.Contact
,c.message
into newtable
from chat a
inner join chat_message_join b on a.chat_ID=b.chat_ID
inner join chat_ID c on c.messageID=b.messageID
```